# Unity gameObject character stuck in T pose for scene but animations work fine when playing game

Tags: unity, editors

[image: stuck]

I want to put a sword in his hand but it is difficult in that T pose.
I have a nice idle animation from Mixamo (model also from Mixamo) that transitions to walk which is working fine.
My other model, playerNinja is in his idle position in the Scene even without playing it, like this:
[image: ninja]

How can I get the top one to get in his idle position in the Editor Scene tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome!

By default, your model will always be on TPose in Edit Mode, this is because the skeleton of your model was setup like that when it was modeled by Mixamo. The only way to display, or preview your animations, would be by using the Animation window, selecting your animation (while selecting your model with an Animator component attached to it), and hit on the "Preview" button.

I would not recommend to use the second model you have, since it's there only for demonstration purposes. You should only use one model (the one with the TPose) with as many animations as you wish, but not otherwise (many models with different animations each one, for only one character. Though there may be a reason on why you would want that setup). Performance and final file size (the size of your build) are the primary concern here.

Anyway, you'll need to adjust the sword in relation to the TPose of the character, that's usually how it's done. I *think* that if you preview the animation and lock the animation window, you could technically adjust the sword according to the animation in preview, but I have never tried that before.